# How to add Django model ImageField to ReportLab

Tags: django, reportlab

I would like to add a media file to PDF generated by Reportlab.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
output STATIC_ROOT --> project/static/

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
output STATIC_ROOT --> project/media/
```

when i draw static images are ok:

```
logo = STATIC_ROOT + "img/dilains-logotipo-bg-white-290x100.jpg"
self.canvas.drawImage(logo, self.x, self.y, w, h, preserveAspectRatio=True)
```

but with media:

```
output self.rejection.img_general_model_1 --> images/treatments/rejections/mouth.jpg
picture = MEDIA_ROOT + str(self.rejection.img_general_model_1)
self.canvas.drawImage(picture, self.x + text_x * 0, self.y, w, h, preserveAspectRatio=True, mask='auto')
```

Throws error:

```
Cannot open resource "/project/media/images/treatments/rejections/mouth.jpg"
<class 'OSError'>
```

Anybody know how to fix it ?
And in production with AWS S3 configuration ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post full traceback

Comment: Inside try - catch this is the exact error traceback: `Cannot open resource "/project/media/images/treatments/rejections/mouth.jpg"
<class 'OSError'>`

Comment: Please post the contents of urls.py Or just check if you have concatenated `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` with `urlpatterns`

Comment: Yes, i have this config done